# I can't override a method of a class imported from cocoapods in swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I've installed a pod from cocoapods named SwiftHSVColorPicker. It's working fine. But when I try to subclass one class of this pod (which is a public class), it's given an error when trying to override the method hueAndSaturationSelected(hue:saturation:) saying that the method doesnt exist in the class.Below it's a print of my subclass:
[image]
Below it's a print of the referred method:
[image]

If a try to create the class inside the same folder of the class SwiftHSVColorPicker, it says that swift is not supported for static libraries. (Besides the fact I even dont know if this class would remain there in case of a new pod install ). How to override this method?

Comment: May I ask if you are trying to override this method in an extension ? Maybe you could provide your code so we could help more easily

Comment: @H4Hugo I updated the question with the print.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the 'override' keyword ?

Comment: Yes. It says: Method 'hueAndSaturationSelected(_:saturation:)' with Objective-C selector 'hueAndSaturationSelected:saturation:' conflicts with method 'hueAndSaturationSelected(_:saturation:)' from superclass 'SwiftHSVColorPicker' with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: When I put private in front of the method it avoids error above, but when I call super's method, it keeps saying the class has no member

Comment: It could be that your class needs to subclass NSObject : 

    class A : NSObject { }

Comment: But swift doesn't allow multiple inheritances.

Comment: It does, just separate with a Coma, just like you would do : class myViewController: UITableViewDatasource, UITableviewDelegate { }

Comment: No, it doesn't. Neither NSObject or SwiftHSVColorPicker is a protocol.

Comment: UITableViewDatasource and UITableviewDelegate are protocols

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116386/discussion-between-h4hugo-and-bruno-barros).

Comment: did u solve this? I am having the same problem with Alamofire framework, but only when using cocoapods...:( i am using cocoapods 1.x and i am using nested targets (unit test target inside main target ), but i am having no luck:(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by only importing the file I was overriding. So in your case, instead of having `#import SwiftHSVColorPicker/SwiftHSVColorPicker.h` in the header of your sublcass, you would add `#import SwiftHSVColorPicker/ClassYouAreOverriding.h`